# Temporary pointer before releasing?

Tags: c++, pointers, com, smart-pointers

I've took a look into `atlbase.h` to see how `CComPtr<>` is implemented, and stumbled upon `Release()` function in base class `CComPtrBase<>` which releases the underlaying object like this:

```
// Release the interface and set to NULL
void Release() throw()
{
    T* pTemp = p;
    if (pTemp)
    {
        p = NULL;
        pTemp->Release();
    }
}
```

My intelect is not good enough to see what's the point of this temporary pointer `pTemp`?

Why this code isn't just:

```
   void Release() throw()
   {
       if (p)
       {
           p->Release();

           // EDIT:
           p = NULL;
       }
   }
```

Now if you take a look at destructor, the destructor is defined just like my expectation from above sample, what is the difference?

Comment: The second version doesn't set `p = NULL;` for one thing.

Comment: ah, ok, I've edited that, but the question remains the same.

Comment: Makes it safe when two threads call Release() concurrently.  The memory barrier is in the implementation's Release function.

Comment: This doesn't protect against concurrent access because the fetch and nulling out of p is not interlocked. What it protects against is reentrant access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two possible explanations here:

1. If `p->Release()` throws then it will not be set to `NULL` in the second variant, while it will in the first. Note that the enclosing function is declared `throw()` so it shouldn't be throwing exceptions. It's possible that this function was written before the `throw()` specifier was added. (Or maybe the coder is used to coding defensively in these kinds of situations and used a common pattern.)
2. The first variant can be tail-call optimized while the second one cannot.